# TextAnnotation shows ibeam cursor, has CanEditText set to true, but will not allow edit

Tags: wpf, scichart

I've got several different types of charts in my application, and the TextAnnotations edit perfectly on 2/3 of them, but I've got one type of chart that is defying me.

While I can add,  and move the annotations on this chart just like the others, and I get the IBeam cursor as if its about to let me edit, select text, it merely never does.

Any ideas on things I could look at would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, SO question asking guidelines require as much info as possible to understand or reproduce a problem. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update / edit your question + comment here when done

Comment: Does your underlying ViewModel property has a public setter?

Comment: Roger, I assume you are talking about the Text property? Annotations on both Surfaces share the same ViewModel and the setters are all public. I only bind to the X1, Y1 and Text properties at present as the annotations are added to the Chart ViewModel in Code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [SciChart Documentation for TextAnnotation](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/v5.x/webframe.html#The%20TextAnnotation%20Type.html):

> The TextAnnotation type draws a TextBlock with optional background at X1,Y1. The text is editable when the use clicks on the TextBlock and **TextAnnotation.IsEditable = true**.

If your text annotations are declared in the same way, do not have differing templates or styles, and all have IsEditable true, then it sounds like they should be editable and you have discovered a bug.

Try the latest build from [SciChart's NuGet feed](https://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17232/37/getting-nightly-builds-with-nuget). If the bug still occurs I would suggest sending code and steps to reproduce to their [Tech Support](https://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit).